# International Chars in UIAlertView on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm having trouble displaying international chars in `UIAlertView`.

I'm retrieving strings in JSON format from [this](http://kancelarijahatipovic.com/translate.php?from=eng&dest=hr&phrase=iron) URL.

The returned format is ok and it contains the correct characters.

When I try to load it in my app in an `UIAlertView` I see this:

[image]

What is the right way to display Unicode characters from Spanish, Croatian, Chinese, etc?

Changing the default language in the settings did not solve the problem.

Comment: How are you decoding the json?

Comment: we are using sbjsonparser

Comment: Can you post your code getting the strings out of JSON and assigning them to the UIAlertView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code, it's quite difficult to point out where you're going wrong.  The code below works, I can only assume you're doing something particularly fruity with the encoded data.

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kancelarijahatipovic.com/translate.php?from=eng&dest=hr&phrase=iron"]] returningResponse:nil error:nil];    
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
id returnVal = [parser objectWithString:string];  
if( [returnVal isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {  
    //build string  
    NSMutableString *alertString = [NSMutableString string];    
    if( [returnVal objectForKey:@"tuc"] != nil ) {  
        NSArray *tucs = [returnVal objectForKey:@"tuc"];  

        for( id tucObject in tucs ) {  
            if( [tucObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && [tucObject objectForKey:@"phrase"] != nil ) {  
                id phraseObject = [tucObject objectForKey:@"phrase"];  

                if( [phraseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && [phraseObject objectForKey:@"text"] != nil )  {  
                    [alertString appendFormat:@"%@\n", [phraseObject objectForKey:@"text"]];  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    if( alertString.length > 0 ) {  
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"example" message:alertString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];  
        [alertView show];  
    }  
}
```

Edit: the SBJsonParser `objectWithData:` provides the same result as above.

Comment: this worked, NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]; did the trick, thanks!